# Pandas - Read a table from excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a table from excel in Pandas. But, I am not able to do it.

For example, the below code works for me and it reads the data from **Sheet1** on **File.xlsx** file

```
df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
```

But there is a table in that sheet called as "Table4" and I want to read that inside pandas using Python.

[image: The table looks like]

The table grows both row wise and column wise. Only the name of the table doesn't change. The contents on the side of the table also changes.

Is it possible to do it using Pandas or can you suggest me the alternatives.

Comment: Can you share a picture of your excel containing the table?

Comment: What is the version of pandas that you are using?

Comment: @MayankPorwal 0.19.2 -

Comment: @meW added now. Thank you

Comment: AFAIK, there is no option to read a determined object. Workarounds always read the entire thing and then slice accordingly

Comment: @Sid29 I believe in pandas version `0.22` and above this issue was resolved. Try upgrading your pandas version. It should read the table easily.

Answer (score 5):

Pandas does not have a current method to read a table directly, but this function below can do so using the `openpyxl` library (which is what pandas uses for reading current excel files).

Note that this technique is from a blog post that I did not author ([found here](https://samukweku.github.io/data-wrangling-blog/spreadsheet/python/pandas/openpyxl/2020/05/19/Access-Tables-In-Excel.html)), although my code is slightly different.

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

def read_table(file_name: str, table_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name, read_only= False, data_only = True) # openpyxl does not have table info if read_only is True; data_only means any functions will pull the last saved value instead of the formula
    for sheetname in wb.sheetnames: # pulls as strings
        sheet = wb[sheetname] # get the sheet object instead of string
        if table_name in sheet.tables: # tables are stored within sheets, not within the workbook, although table names are unique in a workbook
            tbl = sheet.tables[table_name] # get table object instead of string
            tbl_range = tbl.ref #something like 'C4:F9'
            break # we've got our table, bail from for-loop
    data = sheet[tbl_range] # returns a tuple that contains rows, where each row is a tuple containing cells
    content = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in data] # loop through those row/cell tuples
    header = content[0] # first row is column headers
    rest = content[1:] # every row that isn't the first is data
    df = pd.DataFrame(rest, columns = header)
    wb.close()
    return df
```

versions:

```py
In [50]: pd.__version__
Out[50]: '1.3.5'

In [51]: openpyxl.__version__
Out[51]: '3.0.9'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The signal:noise on this topic is utterly horrid, especially for something that really should be in pandas.read_excel to begin with.